# How to show convergence of my generalized Fourier Series to the values I specify in the body of this question.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, fourier-series, sturm-liouville

This question is related to another one I asked earlier [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2030456/write-generalized-fourier-series-for-fx-1-in-terms-of-the-eigenfunctions-f).

For reference, I asked for help writing a generalized Fourier Series for the function $f(x) = 1$ for $0<x<1$, in terms of the eigenfunctions $\displaystyle w_{n} = \cos \left[\left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right)\pi x \right]$, $n = 0,1,2, \cdots$ for the Sturm-Liouville problem:

$\begin{matrix}
- w^{\prime\prime} (x) = \mu w(x) \\
w^{\prime}(0) = w(1) = 0.
\end{matrix}$

With the help of the person who answered me, I was able to successfully show that $\displaystyle \tilde{f}(x) = \tilde{f}_{E}(x) \sim \frac{1}{2}a_{0} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n} \cos \left[ \left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right)\pi x \right] \\ \displaystyle = \frac{1}{2(1)}\int_{-1}^{1}1\, dx +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n} \cos \left[ \left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right)\pi x \right] \\ \displaystyle  = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n} \cos \left[ \left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right)\pi x \right]  \\ \displaystyle = 1 + \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}(2n-1)^{-1}\cdot \cos \left[ \left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right) \pi x \right]$

is the generalized Fourier Series I sought.

Now, however, I am having trouble showing the convergence

According to the back of my book, this series should converge pointwise to

$\tilde{f}(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if}\, |x|<1 \\
0 & \text{if}\, 1 < |x|<2 \end{cases}$

$\tilde{f}(x) = \tilde{f}(x+4)$ for all $x$.

Now, there's a theorem in my book that says that if $f$ and $f^{\prime}$ are both sectionally continuous on $(a,b)$, then the series converges pointwise to $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\left[f(x^{+}) + f(x^{-1}) \right]$ at each $x \in (a,b)$ (where $f(x^{+})$ is the limit of $f$ as we approach $x$ from the right, and $f(x^{-})$ is the limit of $f$ as we approach $x$ from the left)

Since $f(x) = 1$ on $0 < x < 1$, by this theorem, it makes sense that $\tilde{f}$ should converge pointwise to $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\left[ 1 + 1 \right] = \frac{1}{2}(2) = 1$ at each $x \in (0, 1)$.

**But, where does the $|x|<1$ come into play? And also, why does $\tilde{f}$ converge pointwise to $0$ for $1 < |x| < 2$? Why did we start caring about what happens between $1$ and $2$? Does this have something to do with the $2L$-periodic extension (I suppose here, then, since $L = 1$, it would be the $2$-periodic extension), and if so, how?**

**Furthermore, where does the $\tilde{f} = \tilde{f} (x+4)$ come from?**

I ask you to please be patient with me, and not get frustrated that I don't know these things, even if they are very basic to the study of Fourier Series. I'm just trying to learn and getting very confused in the process. By helping me get un-confused, you're doing a very good deed!  Thank you.

Comment: Did you only calculate $a_0$? What about the other coefficients $a_n$?

Comment: @user159517 fixed! Thank you for bringing that to my attention; otherwise, I would never have been able to figure out why I wasn't getting any answers!

Comment: And you need to look at the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts needed for proving the Dirichlet test

Comment: @user1952009 I don't need to prove the Dirichlet test, I need to prove that my Fourier series specifically converges to $1$ for $|x|<1$ and to $0$ for $1<|x|<2$.

Comment: @JessyCat Very funny. You need the Dirichlet test (or the summation by parts) for proving it converges. And this is very elemenary, so just prove it.

Comment: @user1952009 No I'm serious. We have a theorem that says that it converges: If $f$ and $f^{\prime}$ are both sectionally continuous on $(a,b)$, then the series converges pointwise to $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}[f(x^{+})+f(x^{-})]$ at each $x \in (a,b)$, where $f(x^{+})$ is the limit from the right, and $f(x^{-})$ is the limit from the left. In $(-1,1)$, since $f$ is identically 1, I get from that theorem that it converges pointwise to $1$, but I don't know how to use that theorem to show that on $1<|x|<2$ it converges pointwise to $0$. This is all I've wanted to know for the past 4 hours.

Comment: @user1952009 please. I'm desperate. I've spent 4 hours on something that doesn't have anything to do with what I was asking and I'm at my wits end. Please help me.

Comment: Did you realize your series is just a Fourier series ? So all you need is reading a course on the Fourier series, where a similar example is treated in details (using the Dirichlet kernel, or alternatively using the power series for $- \log(1-z)$)

Comment: @user1952009 yes, I know it's a fourier series. I just want to show that it converges pointwise to $0$ on $1<|x|<2$. And I don't know how to do that. Could you please show me how?

Comment: Search for [fourier series dirichlet kernel](http://spot.colorado.edu/~baggett/fourier5.pdf)

Comment: @JessyCat Come on. Nobody will write a course on the Fourier series just for you. So now work.

Comment: @user1952009 I wasn't trying to. It just didn't look like anything we've seen in my pdes (not Fourier series) class. We only touched upon convergence of Fourier series very briefly. And we never mentioned Dirichlet Kernels. Ever.

Comment: If you prefer then play with $-\log(1-z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}$ and show it stays valid for $|z| = 1, z \ne 1$. But the best for you is to read a course on the Fourier series (and the Dirichlet kernel)

Comment: @user1952009 the Dirichlet kernel is the collection of functions $\sum_{k=-n}^{n}e^{ikx}= 1 + 2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos(kx) = \frac{\sin((n+1/2)x)}{\sin(x/2)}$, which I'll admit looks similar to the Fourier series I came up with for this problem: $ 1 + \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}(2n-1)^{-1}\cdot \cos \left[ \left( n - \frac{1}{2}\right) \pi x \right]$. But, not exactly, because I've got that $(2n-1)$ in the denominator, and the alternating term.

Comment: The Dirichlet kernel is important because if $c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(x) e^{-in x}dx$ then $\sum_{n=-N}^N c_n e^{inx} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(x-y) D_N(y)dy$ and the convergence of this integral as $N \to \infty$ (i.e. of the Fourier series) depends on the behavior of $f(x-y) D_N(y)$ around $y = 0$

Comment: @user1952009 I'm still very confused. The $c_{n}$ are the regular fourier coefficients, right? You said Dirichlet Kernel, so I'm like hey, I know what a kernel is, so those will be values of $x$ where my fourier series will converge to $0$, but if I plug in what I know into the expression $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x-y)D_{N}(y)dy$, I get $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} 1\cdot \cos[(n-\frac{1}{2})\pi x]dx$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}\cos((n-1/2)\pi x)}{n}$ converges for $|x|<1$, we can simply apply [Dircichlet's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test#Statement).

To do so, we need only show that there exists a number $L$ such that for any $N$, we have for any fixed $x_0 \in (0,1)$ (or $x_0\in (-1,0)$)

$$\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^{n+1}\cos((n-1/2)\pi x_0)\right|&=\left|\sec(\pi x_0/2)\sin^2\left(\frac{N\pi (x_0-1)}{2}\right)\right| \tag 1\\\\
&\le \sec(\pi x_0/2)\\\\
&=L
\end{align}$$

---

To arrive at $(1)$, we use the sum angle formula $\cos(x)\cos(y)=\frac{\cos(x+y)+\cos(x-y)}{2}$ with $x=\pi x_0/2$ and $y=(n-1/2)\pi x_0$.  Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\cos(\pi x_0/2)\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^{n+1}\cos((n-1/2)\pi x_0)&= \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\left((-1)^{n+1}\cos(n\pi x_0)-(-1)^n\cos((n-1)\pi x_0)\right)}{2}\\\\
&=\frac12\left((-1)^{N+1}\cos(N\pi x_o)+1\right)\\\\
&=\frac12 \left(1-\cos(N\pi(x_0-1)) \right)\\\\
&=\sin^2\left(\frac{N\pi(x_0-1)}{2}\right)
\end{align}$$

---

It was established in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2030456/write-generalized-fourier-series-for-fx-1-in-terms-of-the-eigenfunctions-f/2030518#2030518) that the eigenfunctions $\cos((n-1/2)\pi x)$ form a complete orthogonal set on $(0,1)$, and that we can therefore represent the function $f(x)=1$ by the series

$$1\sim \frac4\pi \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n-1}\cos((n-1/2)\pi x)$$

for $x\in (0,1)$.

Now, note that $\cos((n-1/2)\pi x)$ has period $4$.  To do this, we write

$$\begin{align}
\cos((n-1/2)\pi (x+4))&=\cos((n-1/2)\pi x)\cos((n-1/2)4\pi)-\sin((n-1/2)\pi x)\sin((n-1/2)4\pi)\\\\
&=\color{blue}{\cos((n-1/2)\pi x)}\color{red}{\cos((2n-1)2\pi)}-\color{green}{\sin((n-1/2)\pi x)}\color{purple}{\sin((2n-1)2\pi)}\\\\
&=\color{blue}{\cos((n-1/2)\pi x)}\color{red}{1}-\color{green}{\sin((n-1/2)\pi x)}\color{purple}{0}\\\\
&=\cos((n-1/2)\pi x)
\end{align}$$

Similarly, we see that $\cos((n-1/2)\pi x)=\cos((n-1/2)\pi (2-x-2))=-\cos((n-1/2)(2-x))$.  Therefore, for $x\in (1,2)$,

$$\begin{align}1 & \sim \frac4\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n-1}\cos((n-1/2)\pi (2-x))\\\\
&=-\frac4\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n-1}\cos((n-1/2)\pi x)
\end{align}$$

and hence for $x\in (1,2)$, we have

$$\frac4\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n-1}\cos((n-1/2)\pi x) \sim -1$$

Putting it together, we see that

$$\frac4\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n-1}\cos((n-1/2)\pi x)=\begin{cases}1&,0<x<1\\\\-1&,1<x<2\end{cases}$$

Finally, adding $1$ and dividing by $2$ yields

$$\frac12 +\frac2\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n-1}\cos((n-1/2)\pi x)=\begin{cases}1&,0<x<1\\\\0&,1<x<2\end{cases}$$

Comment: but what about for $1 < |x| < 2$?

Comment: The same approach applies for $x\in (1,2)$ also.

Comment: I'm also confused by how you know that $\displaystyle \left \vert \sum_{n=1}^{N}(-1)^{n+1}\cos(n-1/2)\pi x) \right \vert  = \left \vert \sec(\pi x/2)\sin^{2}\left( \frac{N \pi (x-1)}{2}\right) \right \vert$...

Comment: also, why do we care about what's going on on $(1,2)$? It seems like that just came up kind of randomly in the answer. Could you explain that a bit more?

Comment: There are several ways we can show that equality. One way that is straightforward is to write $\cos(x)=\text{Re}(e^{ix})$.  This amounts to summing the (finite) geometric progression.

Comment: that seems a bit beyond the scope of my course. It's a PDEs class where they're not really assuming we know anything much about complex variables. Why can't we just use the theorem I referred to above to show that the series converges to $1$ on $(0,1)$? Of course, that doesn't help me much with negative $x$'s. Nor apparently does it help me for $x \in (1,2)$. I am still extremely confused.

Comment: There are other approaches.  But using Euler's Identity does not seem beyond the scope in a PDE course.

Comment: again, what about the theorem I cited above?

Comment: Of course, you can apply such a theorem.

Comment: great. Now, why do we care about what's going on on $(1,2)$?

Comment: @Dr.MV $\sec(\pi x/2)\sin^2(\frac{N\pi (x-1))}{2})$ is un-necessiraly complicated, use the $\frac{e^{i \pi N x}-1}{e^{i \pi x}-1}$ form instead

Comment: @user1952009 Clearly for fixed $x\in (0,1)$, the "unnecessarily complicated" term is bounded.  But you are welcome to post another solution of course.  Happy Holidays. ;-))

Comment: It is not obvious it is correct and that it is bounded for every $x,N$, since $\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n \cos(\pi n x)$ is not.

Comment: @user1952009 Fix $x_0 \in (0,1)$.  Clearly the sine function is bounded by $1$, while $\sec (\pi x_0/2)=\frac{1}{\cos(\pi x_0/2)}$ is also bounded.

Comment: @Dr.MV yes this is assuming what you wrote is correct

Comment: @user1952009 It should be straightforward for you to derive this result.

Comment: @user1952009 I've edited to add the derivation of the identity that you had asked about.  The way forward relied only on standard trigonometric identities and the summation of a telescoping series.  Let me know if this suffices.

Comment: @Dr.MV I was able to reproduce your result down to $\displaystyle = \frac{1}{2}\left( 1- \cos\left( N \pi \left( x_{0} - 1 \right) \right) \right)$. From this step to the next step, however, it appears as though you used some form of the identity $\sin^{2}\theta = \frac{1-\cos(2\theta)}{2}$, although that identity is not valid for $N>2$. This is probably not what you were doing, so would you please tell me what identity you used to get that $\displaystyle = \frac{1}{2}\left( 1- \cos\left( N \pi \left( x_{0} - 1 \right) \right) \right) = \sin^{2} \left( \frac{N\pi(x_{0}-1)}{2}\right)$? Thanks.

Comment: @JessyCat The identity $2\sin^2(z/2)=1-\cos(z)$ is valid for all $z$.  Let $z=N\pi (x_0-1)$.  Then, $2\sin^2\left(\frac{N\pi (x_0-1)}2\right)=1-\cos(N\pi (x_0-1))$.  Why do you believe that this is not valid for $N>2$??  In any case, certainly $|1-\cos(z)|\le 2$.  So, we obtain the same bound.

Comment: @Dr.MV but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Half-angle_formulae

Comment: Jessy, I see nothing that invalidates my development.

Comment: @Dr.MV the link had some combinatorial formulas for $\cos(n\theta)$ and a completely different formula for $\cos(3 \theta) = cos^{3}\theta -3\sin^{2} \theta$. I haven't been able to reconcile them.

Comment: Jessy, we're not trying to express $\cos(nx)$ in terms of polynomials of $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$.  We're simply using the identity $2\sin^2(z/2)=1-\cos(z)$, which is valid for all $z$ including when $z=(N\pi (x_0-1))$.

Comment: @Dr.MV okay, so assuming everything is correct, how do I modify this in order to apply it to the case where $x\in (1,2)$ in order to show that the series converges to $0$? You said the same approach applies for it also, but I don't understand how. It might be straightforward for you, but it's not for me.

Comment: The bound applies for $x_0\ne 1$, $x_0\ne 2$, $x_0\ne 3$, etc.  So, it applies for $1<x_0<2$.

Comment: @Dr.MV but how does that show that the series converges specifically to $0$ for all $x_{0}$ on that interval?

Comment: It shows that the series converges pointwise.  It does not give the value to which the series converges.

Comment: @Dr.MV, well I was asking you how to show that it converges specifically to $0$ on that interval. That's what I've been spending hte past few hours trying to figure out.

Comment: Jessy, the title of the post is ?

Comment: @Dr.MV read the parts that I bold faced. Not just the title of the post.

Comment: The quote "Now, however, I am having trouble showing the convergence," led me to believe that you wanted a way to show pointwise convergence.

Comment: @Dr.MV no I wanted to show specifically that for $|x|<1$ the series converges to $1$ and that for $1 < |x|< 2$ the series converges to $0$. That's why I wasn't happy with this answer, because it did not do that, and whenever I asked follow-up questions about it, you ignored them.

Comment: Jessy, I believe that I've been more than patient.  What have I ignored?  And given that I'm the only one who has indulged the battery of questions, I admonish you to refrain from the criticism.

Comment: @Dr.MV wow that was not nice

Comment: What was not nice??

Comment: @Dr.MV you ignored when I was asking why we care what is happening on $(1,2)$

Comment: Jessy, for $x\in (1,2)$, write $x=x-1+1$ and apply the addition angle formula.  See what ensues.

Comment: @Dr.MV I don't want to show that it converges pointwise there; I want to show that it converges specifically to $0$ there. Does that method do that for me?

Comment: Yes, it should since you have already shown that it converges to $1$ for $x\in (0,1)$.  Try letting $x=x-1+1$ and see what happens.  I'm certain that you can do this on your own.

Comment: @Dr.MV I hope ou're right, because I'm having a panic attack right now so much that it physically hurts me.

Comment: Calm down.  You can do it.  I have confidence in you.

Comment: @Dr.MV how did I show that it converges to $1$ for $x \in (0,1)$? The theorem I cited earlier? Because the one you had me proving doesn't show that it converges to $1$, it shows that it just converges pointwise in general to some value, not necessairly $1$.

Comment: Also, @Dr.MV could you please tell me why $\tilde{f}(x) = \tilde{f}(x+4)$?

Comment: @Dr.MV $\frac{1}{2}[f(x^{+})-f(x^{-})]$? I'm supposed to let $x = x-1+1$ in there, and that's going to give me that the fourier series converges to $0$? How? The function $f$ is identically 1, isn't it?

Comment: I have to go now.  Let's continue tomorrow.

Comment: @Dr.MV I can't. I have to have this done by Monday.. I've already lost an entire day and I can't do any more problems until I have this one done. Please don't leave now.

Comment: Jessy, note that the cosine is even.  Then write $$\cos((n-1/2)\pi x)=\cos((n-1/2)\pi (2-x-2))=-\cos((n-1/2)(2-x))$$Then, note that for $x\in(1,2)$, $2-x\in(0,1)$.  And there it is.

Comment: @Dr.MV what identity did you use to go from $\cos(n-1/2)\pi(2-x-2)) = - \cos((n-1/2)(2-x))$? Is that where the evenness comes in? And if so, where does the $\pi$ go?

Comment: And I think it should be positive, because $\cos$ is even, and shifting it down by a period of $2\pi$ shouldn't change the sign.

Comment: The period is $4$, not $2$.

Comment: @Dr.MV thank you! That finally made so much sense! You really are a saint, you know that? ;)

Comment: @JessyCat Jessy. You're welcome.  It was my pleasure and I'm pleased to hear that this was helpful.  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV it took me a while, but eventually I got it. I also tried to apply this to the case where we want to do expansion of $f(x) = 1$ in terms of different eigenfunctions, $\sin((n-1/2)\pi x)$. I had another question posted, and I just edited the question to include a full-on solution, based on the method you provided here. The only thing I'm not sure about is that I wound up getting a $+ \frac{1}{2}$ term there as well, which seems weird for odd eigenfunctions. Maybe it's because the function $f(x) =1$ is an even function? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure @Dr. MV already answered your question, just want to add something to the discussion that may help. Consider the function

$$
f(x)=\begin{cases} 1\quad \mbox{for}\quad |x| < 1 \\ 0\quad \mbox{for}\quad 1<|x|<2 \end{cases}
$$

I would like to make a Fourier expansion of $f(x)$. Since the series is periodic in nature we need to make a periodic extension of $f$ and because $f$ is even in its domain, the natural choice for the extension $\tilde{f}$ is to make it even as well with period $L$

$$
\tilde{f}(x + L)= \tilde{f}(x)
$$

$L=4$ comes from the $\tilde{f}(x)$ has to be $f(x)$ for $|x|<2$

The [Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) for $\tilde{f}$ is simply

$$
\tilde{f}(x) = \frac{1}{2}a_0 + \sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty}a_n \cos \frac{2\pi n x}{L} + b_n \sin \frac{2\pi n x}{L} \tag{1}
$$

where

$$
a_0 = \frac{2}{L}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}{\rm d}x\; \tilde{f}(x) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-2}^{2}{\rm d}x\; f(x) = 1
$$

$$
a_n = \frac{2}{L}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}{\rm d}x\; \tilde{f}(x) \cos\frac{2\pi n x}{L}= \frac{1}{2}\int_{-2}^{2}{\rm d}x\; f(x)\cos\frac{\pi n x}{2} = \frac{2}{n\pi}\sin\frac{n\pi}{2} \quad n =1,2,\cdots
$$

and

$$
b_n = \frac{2}{L}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}{\rm d}x\; \tilde{f}(x) \sin\frac{2\pi n x}{L}= \frac{1}{2}\int_{-2}^{2}{\rm d}x\; f(x)\sin\frac{\pi n x}{2} = 0 \quad n =1,2,\cdots
$$

Note that

$$
a_{2k} = 0 \quad\mbox{and}\quad a_{2k - 1} = \frac{2}{(2k-1)\pi}(-1)^k \qquad k =1,2,\cdots
$$

Eq. (1) then becomes

$$
\tilde{f}(x) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k = 1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k-1}\cos \left((k - 1/2)\pi x\right) \tag{2}
$$

Which is basically what you have before. The figure below shows $f(x)$ and $\tilde{f}(x)$ truncated with 20 terms in the sum

[image]

Comment: @cavernac it's interesting - you showed convergence by working backwards? I suppose in that case, you'd have to know the convergence beforehand, but what if you didn't? Also, what if we had an even function like $f(x)=1$, but we had to write our Fourier Series in terms of odd eigenfunctions?

Comment: @JessyCat Actually the convergence is ensured by the fact that a Fourier series will converge to the value of $f(x)$ if $f$ is continuos at $x$, and to the midpoint of the discontinuity otherwise. In the case you want to write $\tilde{f}$ in terms of odd eigenfunctions you just make an odd extension of $f(x) = 1$ as we did [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2031072/need-to-discuss-convergence-i-e-what-values-it-converges-to-on-what-intervals?noredirect=1#comment4169610_2031072)